# JQuery UI Autocompete Both Multi Search and Limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete and trying to both allow multiple searches and limit results. After trawling through SO I am still none the wiser how to do these to things together - I can do them individually.

This is the standard jQuery UI code to allow multiple searches

```
    source: function( request, response ) {
    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    }
```

And this is the code to limit results:

```
      maxResults: 10,
      source: function( request, response ) {
      var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
      response(results.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
     }
```

I have tried so many different things but cant seam to get them to work together!

How do I do both - Limit and Multiple searching? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happend since you try to slice request.term without you extracted it, so that just add a `extractLast` to your filter code and its will be work fine...

check live example here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgsz5yjf/)

```
source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast( request.term ));
      console.log(results);
      response(results.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
        },
```